# How to cycle in Eclipse through errors only?

Tags: java, eclipse

Using Ctrl+, for Previous and Ctrl+. for Next one can cycle through warnings and errors in code. Can this be narrowed to only cycle through errors?

Please note that I don't want to hide the warnings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change what annotations are viewed with these shortcuts in the Next/Previous annotation dropdown. Remove "Warnings" and leave errors will make the cycling only focus on errors. Instructions on changing these setting at:

http://eclipseone.wordpress.com/2010/03/10/navigate-and-fix-errors-amp-warnings-in-a-class-with-eclipse-keyboard-shortcuts/

Comment: It would be really nifty if eclipse could cycle through the annotiations by priority - first the errors, and then the warnings. Unfortunately it doesn't do that. :-/